# How do I split a dataframe by a list of numbers of rows for each chunk?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I want to cut up according to the elements in a list. For example, I have a `range_list[16, 14, 2...]`

I then want to cut up the dataframe so that the first chunk will be 16 rows long, the second part 14, the third part 2.. etc. It could be beneficial to put this in a list as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html). This can take a range of indices to slice on, so will require you to [`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) your range list.

```
indices = np.cumsum(range_list, dtype=np.int32)

np.split(df, indices)
```

### Example

```
range_list = [16, 14, 2]

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(sum(range_list), 2))

indices = np.cumsum(range_list, dtype=np.int32)

np.split(df, indices)
```

[returns]

Returns a list with 3 `DataFrames` in this example, of shapes `(16, 2)` , `(14, 2)` & `(2, 2)`

```
[           0         1
 0   1.060679  1.092185
 1  -0.043971 -1.394001
 2   1.106233 -0.711420
 3  -0.585148  0.179987
 4  -0.871562  0.730840
 5   0.810119 -0.130510
 6  -0.957646 -0.324547
 7   0.235788 -0.460025
 8  -0.262714 -0.496833
 9   0.454519 -1.244402
 10  0.084796  1.587114
 11 -0.353880  1.110543
 12 -0.570345  0.774158
 13  1.772536  1.283950
 14 -1.682226 -0.376789
 15  0.956894  0.081805,            0         1
 16  0.014841  0.110091
 17 -0.408881  0.260970
 18  0.004939  0.940186
 19 -2.056951  0.353928
 20  0.618294 -2.201036
 21  1.375224  0.526367
 22 -0.424886 -1.253565
 23  1.785862  0.774936
 24 -0.341340 -1.056191
 25 -0.274463 -1.637185
 26  1.596336  2.311630
 27 -0.479840  1.021640
 28 -1.307765 -0.232664
 29  0.243427  0.339242,            0         1
 30  0.345476  0.331306
 31  0.895437 -1.163441, Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [0, 1]
 Index: []]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make this work with float values? I have floats in my df, and get the error message: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: You can't slice with floats... For example, there is no index `2.5` of a list. Indices must be integers

Comment: If you mean that there are float dtypes in `range_list` (I'm hoping only `x.0` values), then use `indices = np.cumsum(range_list, dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Comment: Actually, it still gives the error TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.
If you just want to split the list you can do something like this:

```
def split_list(l, range_list):
    i = 0
    for x in range_list:
        start = i
        end = start + x
        print(l[start:end])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with the cumulative sum of the list elements, add an initial zero, and a final -1, then iterate over it for slicing the initial dataframe:

```py
ls = [16,14,2, ..]
chucks = np.cumsum(ls)
c=np.zeros(len(chucks)+2)

c[1:-1] = chucks
c[-1] = -1

all_dfs= []
for i range(len(c)-1):
    df_list.append(df[c[i]:c[i+1]])
```